# How to vectorize a python function that loops over an array of 3D points?

Tags: python, numpy, numba

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import random

@profile
def point_func(point, points, funct):
    return np.sum(funct(np.sqrt(((point - points)**2)).sum(1)))

@profile
def point_afunc(ipoints, epoints, funct):
    res = np.zeros(len(ipoints))
    for idx, point in enumerate(ipoints):
        res[idx] = point_func(point, epoints, funct)
    return res

@profile
def main():
    points = random((5000,3))
    rpoint = random((1,3))

    pres = point_func(rpoint, points, lambda r : r**3)

    ares = point_afunc(points, points, lambda r : r**3)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

I have profiled it with `kernprof` and gotten this:

```
Timer unit: 1e-06 s

Total time: 2.25667 s File: point-array-vectorization.py Function: point_func at line 4

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
     4                                           @profile
     5                                           def point_func(point, points, funct):
     6      5001    2256667.0    451.2    100.0      return np.sum(funct(np.sqrt(((point - points)**2)).sum(1)))

Total time: 2.27844 s File: point-array-vectorization.py Function: point_afunc at line 8

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
     8                                           @profile
     9                                           def point_afunc(ipoints, epoints, funct):
    10         1          5.0      5.0      0.0      res = np.zeros(len(ipoints))
    11      5001       4650.0      0.9      0.2      for idx, point in enumerate(ipoints):
    12      5000    2273789.0    454.8     99.8          res[idx] = point_func(point, epoints, funct)
    13         1          0.0      0.0      0.0      return res

Total time: 2.28239 s File: point-array-vectorization.py Function: main at line 15

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
    15                                           @profile
    16                                           def main():
    17         1        145.0    145.0      0.0      points = random((5000,3))
    18         1          2.0      2.0      0.0      rpoint = random((1,3))
    19                                           
    20         1        507.0    507.0      0.0      pres = point_func(rpoint, points, lambda r : r**3)
    21                                           
    22         1    2281731.0 2281731.0    100.0      ares = point_afunc(points, points, lambda r : r**3)
```

So this part is taking most of the time:

```
11      5001       4650.0      0.9      0.2      for idx, point in enumerate(ipoints):
    12      5000    2273789.0    454.8     99.8          res[idx] = point_func(point, epoints, funct)
```

I want to see if the time loss is caused by calling the `funct` in a `for` loop. To do this, I would like to vecctorize `point_afunc`, using `numpy.vectorize`. I have tried it, but it seems to vectorize away the points: the loop ends up looping over individual point components.

```
@profile
def point_afunc(ipoints, epoints, funct):
    res = np.zeros(len(ipoints))
    for idx, point in enumerate(ipoints):
        res[idx] = point_func(point, epoints, funct)
    return res

point_afunc = np.vectorize(point_afunc)
```

Leads to an error:

```
  File "point-array-vectorization.py", line 24, in main
    ares = point_afunc(points, points, lambda r : r**3)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 2755, in __call__
    return self._vectorize_call(func=func, args=vargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 2825, in _vectorize_call
    ufunc, otypes = self._get_ufunc_and_otypes(func=func, args=args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 2785, in _get_ufunc_and_otypes
    outputs = func(*inputs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/line_profiler.py", line 115, in wrapper
    result = func(*args, **kwds)
  File "point-array-vectorization.py", line 10, in point_afunc
    res = np.zeros(len(ipoints))
TypeError: object of type 'numpy.float64' has no len()
```

Somehow, instaed of vectorizing each *point* in `ipoints` it vectorizes across the points' components?

**Edit**: tried the advice from @John Zwinck below and used numba. I got longer execution times with `@jit` than without it. If I remove `@profile` decorator from all functions, and replace it with `@jit` for the `point_func` and `point_afunc`, these are the execution times:

```
time ./point_array_vectorization.py 

real    0m3.686s
user    0m3.584s
sys 0m0.077s
point-array-vectorization> time ./point_array_vectorization.py 

real    0m3.683s
user    0m3.596s
sys 0m0.063s
point-array-vectorization> time ./point_array_vectorization.py 

real    0m3.751s
user    0m3.658s
sys 0m0.070s
```

and with all `@jit` decorators removed:

```
point-array-vectorization> time ./point_array_vectorization.py 

real    0m2.925s
user    0m2.874s
sys 0m0.030s
point-array-vectorization> time ./point_array_vectorization.py 

real    0m2.950s
user    0m2.902s
sys 0m0.029s
point-array-vectorization> time ./point_array_vectorization.py 

real    0m2.951s
user    0m2.886s
sys 0m0.042s
```

Do I need to help the `numba` compiler more?

**Edit**: Can `point_afunc` be written without the for loop using `numpy` somehow?

**Edit**: compared the loop version with the `numpy` broadcasting version by Peter, and the loop version *is faster*:

```
Timer unit: 1e-06 s

Total time: 2.13361 s
File: point_array_vectorization.py
Function: point_func at line 7

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
     7                                           @profile
     8                                           def point_func(point, points, funct):
     9      5001    2133615.0    426.6    100.0      return np.sum(funct(np.sqrt(((point - points)**2)).sum(1)))

Total time: 2.1528 s
File: point_array_vectorization.py
Function: point_afunc at line 11

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
    11                                           @profile
    12                                           def point_afunc(ipoints, epoints, funct):
    13         1          5.0      5.0      0.0      res = np.zeros(len(ipoints))
    14      5001       4176.0      0.8      0.2      for idx, point in enumerate(ipoints):
    15      5000    2148617.0    429.7     99.8          res[idx] = point_func(point, epoints, funct)
    16         1          0.0      0.0      0.0      return res

Total time: 2.75093 s
File: point_array_vectorization.py
Function: new_point_afunc at line 18

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
    18                                           @profile
    19                                           def new_point_afunc(ipoints, epoints, funct):
    20         1    2750926.0 2750926.0    100.0      return np.sum(funct(np.sqrt((ipoints[:, None, :] - epoints[None, :, :])**2).sum(axis=-1)), axis=1)

Total time: 4.90756 s
File: point_array_vectorization.py
Function: main at line 22

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
    22                                           @profile
    23                                           def main():
    24         1        170.0    170.0      0.0      points = random((5000,3))
    25         1          4.0      4.0      0.0      rpoint = random((1,3))
    26         1        546.0    546.0      0.0      pres = point_func(rpoint, points, lambda r : r**3)
    27         1    2155829.0 2155829.0     43.9      ares = point_afunc(points, points, lambda r : r**3)
    28         1    2750945.0 2750945.0     56.1      vares = new_point_afunc(points, points, lambda r : r**3)
    29         1         71.0     71.0      0.0      assert(np.max(np.abs(ares-vares)) < 1e-15)
```

Comment: Is it your intention to provide another funct (in your case lambda r : r**3) at each call? This will have a significant compilation overhead in Numba.

Comment: @max9111: yes, the functions will be different, there is a finite set of functions I want to use however.

Comment: It maybe useful to compile this finite set of functions once ahead of time or using caching. How large is this set of functions?

Comment: @max9111: Thanks! ~15 functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`numpy.vectorize()` does nothing useful in terms of performance: it is just syntactic sugar (or rather, syntactic cyanide) which builds a hidden Python `for` loop.  It won't help you.

One thing that might help you quite a bit is [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/).  It can just-in-time compile your original code and will probably speed it up a lot.  Just replace your `@profile` decorators with `@numba.jit`.

Comment: Doesn't numpy.vectorize make it possible for a function to be executed over a `numpy.ndarray` *without* calling the interpreter within the loop?

Comment: @tmaric: Absolutely not.  The docs say plainly: *"The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop."*

Comment: OK, so this is different from the numba vectorize. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use broadcasting for this.  Broadcasting is the reshaping of the point matrix so that dimensions "broadcast" against eachother.  e.g. `ipoints[:, None, :] - epoints[None, :, :]` says:

- reshape `ipoints` from MxD to Mx1xD
- reshape `epoints` from NxD to 1xNxD
- subtract each pair of points to get a MxNxD array

The full code becomes:

```
def new_point_afunc(ipoints, epoints, funct):
    return np.sum(funct(np.sqrt((ipoints[:, None, :] - epoints[None, :, :])**2).sum(axis=-1)), axis=1)
```

Warning - in your example the dimensionality of a point is only 3, but for higher dimensions this may not be practical memory-wise, because this `ipoints[:, None, :] - epoints[None, :, :]` approach creates an intermediate matrix with shape `(len(ipoints), len(epoints), n_dim)`.

Comment: I just ran `kernprof` with your version, and it seems to be slower than the one with the loop? I have edited the question. Thanks for the help!

Comment: That's a bit surprising, but makes sense - as this "fully vectorized" approach requires allocating more memory for the intermediate subtraction operation.

Answer (score 1):

### Example using Numba

The performance of this approach depends on how often somebody want to call the created functions and on how large the input data is. With a compilation overhead of about 1.67s it is not really suitable to use this approach with relatively small data or calling the function only once.

I have also used your code with minor modifications. Using Numba writing plain loops intead multiple vectorized commands like `np.sum(funct(np.sqrt(((point - points)**2)).sum(1)))` will be faster, both in runtime and compilation time. Additionally this problem can be easily parallelized, but this would additionally increase the compilation.

**Example**

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import random
import numba as nb
import time

def make_point_func(funct):
    @nb.njit(fastmath=True)
    def point_func(point, points):
        return np.sum(funct(np.sqrt(((point - points)**2)).sum(1)))
    return point_func

def make_point_afunc(funct,point_func):
    @nb.njit(fastmath=True)
    def point_afunc(ipoints, epoints):
        res = np.zeros(len(ipoints))
        for idx in range(len(ipoints)):
            res[idx] = point_func(ipoints[idx], epoints)
        return res
    return point_afunc


def main():
  points = random((5000,3))
  rpoint = random((1,3))

  #Make functions
  point_func=make_point_func(nb.njit(lambda r : r**3))
  point_afunc=make_point_afunc(nb.njit(lambda r : r**3),point_func)

  #first call
  print("First call with compilation overhead")
  t1=time.time()
  pres = point_func(rpoint, points)
  ares = point_afunc(points, points)
  print(time.time()-t1)

  print("Second call without compilation overhead")
  t1=time.time()
  #second call
  pres = point_func(rpoint, points)
  ares = point_afunc(points, points)
  print(time.time()-t1)

if __name__=="__main__":
  main()
```

**Performance**

```
original: 1.7s
Numba first call: 1.87s
Numba further calls: 0.2s
```

Comment: What is the reason behind wrapping the functions into `make_` functions? I have tried adding the `njit` decorators directly to the functions, but `numba` fails to compile it, because it fails to infer the third argument of `point_func` (cannot determine Numba type of <class 'function'>). Is the strategy to simply avoid inference of such a type that causes issues, and wrapping the rest, so that `numba` can process it?

Comment: It isn't possible to pass functions to a jitted function directly.https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/faq.html

Comment: Thanks! I did RTFM, but didn't find this, I'm new to numba, there's a ton of info to process.